# Creating a new line when writing to a text file with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-files

I have a function where I grab the .text() of a table in javascript. I strip out the HTML tags, but when I then write it to a text file, I am left with one large blob.

```
function removeHtml(html) {
            var result;
            var rm = new RegExp("</td>", "g");
            result = html.replace(rm, "\n");
            result = $(result).find("td").text();
            alert(result);
            return result;
        }
```

I have considered splitting this into an array and looping over it, but I feel I will run into this problem again:

How do I create a new line when writing this result to the text file? Adding a \n does not add a new line to the .txt file, just makes it look nice in the alert(result) that is in my function.

EDIT: I was told that the \n in my replace needed to be inside quotes. I did this, and added an alert to check the results. The alert has all the new lines in it, but the text file is still one long string. The \n no longer appears in the file.

Comment: Show the code that you use to remove the tags!

Comment: It would probably be a lot less messy to walk the DOM and output text incrementally, applying formatting as necessary, than to RegExp hack at it.

Comment: The second argument to [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a string or a function.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir the $(result).text() removes the tags

Comment: @tadman how do you mean? can you make a jsfiddle to explain?

Comment: `$('tr').forEach(...)` and so on. There's probably already a plugin that does this, mind you.

Comment: @tadman I think you meant `each` not `forEach`!

Comment: The real question is I guess "How do you save this to file?".

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Right you are. That one.

Comment: @TahaPaksu saving it is not the problem I have that working fine and dandy.

Comment: Yes, saving may be the problem. You might have to replace the \\'s into \'s before saving. Then you'd have what you wanted.

Comment: @TahaPaksu I am not sure what you mean. I was never getting \\'s in the download. I must have misunderstood what you were getting at.

Comment: what language do you use to save? It's not javascript or jquery right?

Comment: @TahaPaksuit is indeed. I basically use this: http://jsfiddle.net/TzVd3/918/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the RegExp with `"\n"` or `'\n'`:

```
function removeHtml(html) {
    var result;
    var rm = new RegExp("</td>", "g");
    result = html.replace(rm, "\n");
    result = $(result).text();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and added an alert before I return the results. The alert looks great, but once in the file it is not a new line

Comment: So how do you store that string in the file? And which OS are you using? Does it support `<CR>`, `<LF>` or `<CR><LF>`?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through each tr and accumulate the result like this:

```js
var text = "";  // the accumulator

$("tr").each(function() {
  text += $(this).text() + "\n"; // for each tr add the text followed by new line
});

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>ABC: </td><td>mmm</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Lorem: </td><td>Epsom</td></tr>
  <tr><td>LOL</td><td>MOL</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This was grabbing every tag from the page, while still not inserting new lines